# Is it possible for a ring R to have exactly one zero divisor?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me with this problem? I did as below but my prof said it is wrong. Thanks!

Let a not is 0 is a zero divisor of a ring R

Then there exists a non-zero element b in R such that a.b = b.a = 0

Since a is not 0 then implies b = 0, so b is a zero divisor

Therefore, a ring R can not have exactly one zero divisor.

Comment: Why do you think that $ab=0$ and $a \ne 0$ implies that $b=0$?

Comment: Here is a hint:  what if the non-zero element $a$ and its "partner" $b$ are *the same element*?  Could you have a ring in which one nonzero element (and only one nonzero element) satisfies $a^2=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of a zero divisor:

> A **nonzero** element $a$ of a ring $R$ is called a *zero divisor* if there exists a **nonzero** element $b$ of $R$ so that $ab=0$.

Note the requirement that $a,b$ are nonzero. If we did not have this restriction, then everything would be a zero divisor since $a\cdot 0=0$. So your statement that $b=0$, so $b$ is a zero divisor is wrong. Not only that, $ab=0$ and $a\neq 0$ does not imply $b=0$. This is what being a zero divisor precisely means, that there exists such a **nonzero** $b$! So your proof doesn't really make sense at all.

Rather, notice that $ab=0$ means that $(-a)b=0$. So if $a\neq -a$, then we already have two zero divisors and we are done. Now, $a=-a$ if and only if $2a=0$. Indeed, this case is possible: consider $R=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. It has the unique zero divisor $2$ since $2\cdot 2=0$.

Comment: For another example one could take $\mathbb{F}_2[\epsilon]$.